# What is the purpose of closing old duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The [help section states](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates),

> Once the question is closed as a duplicate, these comments are deleted and the duplicate information is automatically edited into the question itself. Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question.

Two points.

1. This is a little ambiguous to me. What comments get moved? The duplicate information is edited into which question?
2. How valuable is this really? If I'm going to spend significant time trying to clean up duplicate questions, I want that time to be well spent. However, it seems to me that since the question is old, answered and indexed by search engines already, the damage is already done.

Is this all that happens when a question is marked as a duplicate? If not, what happens behind the scenes to rectify these duplicates?

Answer (score 5):

When a possible duplicate is proposed, a comment is added, stating the possible duplicate question.  When it's *actually* closed, the comment is removed.

When the question is actually closed the question itself has a banner added stating that it's a duplicate, and pointing to the canonical question.

It adds value in that people that find the question in the future end up being directed to the canonical post with a quality answer, instead of *not* being directed to the quality post with an actual answer, so yes, it adds value.

Note that anonymous users who navigate to a duplicate question are, under certain circumstances, automatically redirected to the canonical question, so even if the duplicate has a bit of Google juice it still ends up directing (most of) that traffic to the canonical question.

Comment: From what I have seen, anonymous users are only redirected if the duplicate doesn't have answers. Take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/java-iterate-through-hashmap) for example; I wasn't redirected when viewing it in incognito mode.

Comment: If the duplicate is not at all there to attract traffic, won't the users directly find the *canonical question* ?

Comment: Redirection does not take place if the duplicate is highly voted or if it has more than one target.